# Wicket SortableDataProvider - how to sort?

Tags: sorting, wicket

I've got this webpage using Wicket, which loads in some data with some headlines, and then tons of rows beneath with the corresponding data.

Now, I want my data to be able to get sorted when i click on one of the headlines. From what I've found on google, SortableDataProvider is the way to go. But every example I find requires 1 parameter, whereas when I implement it, it requires two. What to do?

My class to sort is this:

```
public class SimpleDataView extends WebPage {

public SimpleDataView() {

    addNumberOfRecords();
    addHeadlines();
    addRecords();
}

private void addNumberOfRecords() {
    Data dataModel = getDataModel().getObject();
    add(new Label("size", "Number of records: " + dataModel.numberOfRecords()));
}

private void addRecords() {
    Data dataModel = getDataModel().getObject();
    ListView records = new ListView("records", dataModel.getRecords()) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            item.add(new ListView("recordColumn", item.getModel()) {

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
                    item.add(new Label("value", item.getModel()));
                }
            });
        }
    };
    add(records);
}

private void addHeadlines() {
    Data dataModel = getDataModel().getObject();
    ListView headlines = new ListView("headlines", dataModel.getHeaders()) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            item.add(new Label("headlineColumn", item.getModel()));
        }
    };
    add(headlines);
}

private IModel<Data> getDataModel() {
    IModel<Data> model = new LoadableDetachableModel<Data>() {

        @Override
        protected Data load() {
            DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandlerImpl();
            return dataHandler.getDataFromSource();
        }
    };
    return model;
}

}
```

Comment: Where is the sorting?

Comment: There is none yet, this is just the wicket class which gives me the data, and this is where i suppose some of the sorting needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example in the Wicket wiki.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Simple+Sortable+DataTable+Example

You can adjust the columns if you need more or less columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SortableDataProvider, you should (when creating columns) define a sortProperty in the column's creation. Every one of the sortable-filterable columns has a constructor, with the possibility to define by hand the sortProperty.
It should by the way be identical to the generated SQL query's part that it points to.